# How do I remove all this silicone on my used vehicle?

Tags: toyota, sparkplugs, camry, coil-on-plug

3 weeks ago I bought a used 2009 Camry le last week the engine light came on and the reading said change ignition coils and spark plugs im pretty handy watched a video and ordered the plugs and coils when I removed the cover my mouth dropped the are drowned in silicone sealant I assume to keep them together what do I use and how do I remove this silicone to replace these connectors? [image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best bet is to use a sharp razor blade and split the silicone where the connector joins onto the coil. Once you've got them separate, you should be able to peel the rest of it off of the connector. While the silicone will stick to the plastic of the connector, it shouldn't completely bond to it. Other than that, you'll just have to meticulously pick at it until you can get all of it off, or at least to a condition where you can get the connector back into place.

Answer (score 3):

So, it's hard to tell with the silicon covering everything, but it looks like the silicon was put there to hold the connector on, because the plastic clip that holds the connector on broken off of the connector. Like the other poster said, slicing the silicon with a razor blade across the seam between coil and connector will work to get it off, but there likely won't be anything holding it on when you put it back together. In that case, the best way to fix that  would be to buy new connector harnesses (sometimes labeled as a "pigtail") for the coils, and splice them onto the old wires. But, if you want you could also just try running a zip tie through the middle of the wires, wrapping around the coil and going through the gap between the coil and bolt, which should hold it in place.

I do just want to add,  too, it looks like the coil on the left in the picture has been pretty recently replaced, so it's pretty unlikely that that one needs to be replaced. It's impossible to say without knowing what your engine codes are, but seeing that on a car you just bought with a code pointing towards it being bad could be a sign of a larger issue. On the other hand the engine light could just be on from a bad connection from those damaged connectors, so you may just want to try fixing that before doing anything else. If you are able to tell me your engine codes I could give you some more specific information.

Comment: Bare in mind that a zip tie could melt in the heat of the engine bay, so that should probably be considered a short-term solution. At a minimum, some spare zip ties should be stored in the glove compartment, so if the car is misfiring or won't start at all, they'll be on hand to re-do the fix.

Comment: Holy smoke yeah, it looks like "the last guy" broke off *all* the latches on those connectors.  Probably because those latches can be *super annoying to get to release* so the guy just took a razor blade to them, and then had to glue them to have them not fall off.  Bad, very bad.  Worse, the fragile latch is often on the hard-to-replace wiring harness and not on the swappable coil or injector.

Comment: @FreeMan A zip tie isn't going to melt in that location. It would need to be basically touching the exhaust for that to happen. Just about every car uses zip ties to hold wire harnesses in the engine bay in place from the factory. Definitely not a bad idea to keep some extras on hand, though.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine Well, to be fair, I doubt that they were broken off intentionally. Those clips can get very brittle with age and they will sometimes break before even moving enough to get the connector off. Luckily, you can buy just the part of the harness going to each coil and splice them on pretty easily.